python module search path, ModuleNotFoundError
I am using zsh on MacOS.
I have a python package structured like this:
app/
|__init__.py
|src/
| |__init__.py
| |base/
| | |__init__.py
| | |settings.py
| | |migrations/
| | | |__init__.py
| | | |commands.py


in which commands.py has one line of code:
from base import settings

I have exported the environment variable:
export PYTHONPATH=/user/Desktop/app

my current directory is:
% pwd
/user/Desktop/app

The Problem
When I try to execute the script:
% python3 src/base/migrations/commands.py

I got this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/javen/Desktop/app/src/base/migrations/commands.py", line 1, in <module>
    from base import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'

I have tried running the script as a module in this command
python3 -m src/base/migrations/commands.py

still not working.

Welcome to StackOverflow! To add to TD88's answer, your code doesn't work because you're searching inside \migrations for a file named base with an object settings. To get the correct result you need to ensure you're searching in the correct directory (.. does this in TD88's answer, moving up to the parent directory).
This SO thread has really helped me in the past to understand import functioniality., when considering how to handle imports.

In your "commands.py" file, use this line instead: from .. import settings. This line will tell python to look for the 'settings' module in the parent directory of migrations, where it is currently. Then, using the same commands, it should work correctly.
